# Display Data in GridView with DataAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, dataadapter

I have try the following code for displaying data from data adapter in gridview.
Following link is for [GridView with DataAdapter Tutorial.](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/31e530dc-59df-44f6-8ccc-183051bc5399/?Display%20Data%20in%20GridView%20in%20Android/)

I am wanted the following output :

[image]

I have follow the tutorial and get the output as i wanted, but unfortunetly when scroll the page,
application will be closed automatically.

**ERROR : "Application Failure Detected, Please Try Again"**

How to resolve these problem?

**code :** main.xml file.

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/gridview"   
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip" />
```

**code :** MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.gridviewdata;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);  
    gridview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(this));
}
```

**code :**  customgrid.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">

              <TextView  android:text="@string/hello_world"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/txtId"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

              <TextView  android:text="@string/hello_world"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/txtName"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**code :** DataAdapter.java file

```
package com.example.gridviewdata;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    private String [] id = {"S001","S002","S003","S004","S005","S006","S007","S008","S009","S010","S011","S012"};
    private String [] name={"Rohit","Rahul","Ravi","Amit","Arun","Anil","Kashif","Nayan","Jay","Sagar","Jairaj","Vishal"};
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public DataAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext=c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return id.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder=null;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtId=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            holder.txtId.setPadding(100, 10,10 , 10);
            holder.txtName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtName.setPadding(100, 10, 10, 10);
            if(position==0)
            {                             
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtId.setText(id[position]);
        holder.txtName.setText(name[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {        
        TextView txtId;
        TextView txtName;
    }
}
```

Give any solution for these problem.
if any other resource is available then give me an reference.

Comment: first  `MainActivity extends Activity` instead of  `MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: and also post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

In getView() method return all items, and i have setting the tag just in the first item,
when android calls again getView for position 1, i am try to get the tag from convertView,
but i didn't called setTag for convertView 1, then getTag returns a null object, and i am try to get the object txtName from a null object, and then the error occurs.

removing the **if(position==0)** then application work perfectly and give the scrolling.